# process and threads consumes a lot of memory after job is done

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, memory

recently I encountered some memory-thread related issue.
Below code creates 5 thread and each thread push_back to vector 500'000'000 int values.
After loop with push_back ends program still uses ~375M of virtual memory and here is my question why process still uses so much memory?

I am using g++ (Ubuntu 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 8.4.0

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
  

void joinAll(vector<thread>& arg)
{
    for(auto& item : arg) item.join();
}

int main()
{

    vector<thread> threads;
    
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        threads.emplace_back([](){
            
            {   // block
                vector<int> data;
                
                for(int idx=0; idx<500'000'000; ++idx)
                {
                        data.push_back(idx);    
                }
            }   // end of block
            
            cout<<"loop is over\n";
            
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5));
            
            });
    }    
    
    cout<<"wait in main\n";  
    
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    
    joinAll(threads);
        
}
```

Image presents `htop` output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RefYv.png)

Comment: You never check for any out of memory / resource handle exceptions. Uncaught exceptions in threads and proceeding execution, may cause overall _undefined behavior_. Loads of opportunities to let your OS stall.

Comment: For the record, this example creates vectors with 1B elements, not 500M. It defines a vector with 500M elements initially, then adds 500M more.

Comment: Virtual memory is not usually returned to the OS the instant it is no longer used. For all the OS knows, the process is about to create another huge vector - there's no point transferring memory back and forth. The OS will reclaim that memory when the process terminates, or when another process asks for virtual memory and the OS doesn't have any lying around. It is more efficient to only reclaim unused memory when under memory pressure - most of the time, there's plenty to go around.

Comment: Compile your C++ code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -g` then use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) to understand the behavior and the [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) done by your executable

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for a process to return its memory back to the OS the moment it is no longer in use. It would also be very inefficient if there were such a requirement.

Also, let's do a quick analysis your program's memory requirements. Assuming a typical case of `int` being 4 bytes, and assuming your threads are running in parallel and finish at similar times, then your program requires about 2.5GB just for your `vector`s, let alone the memory requirements for the threads themselves and any other process memory. The fact that you're only seeing ~375MB usage indicates that the process's memory is largely being returned to the OS.